# Can't create checkboxradio on element.nodeName=input and element.type=text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have following html and when I preview the page, I get following error:

> Can't create checkboxradio on element.nodeName=input and
>   element.type=text

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("input").checkboxradio();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#">
        <label for="cbxForRent">For Rent</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cbxForRent" />
        <input type="text" id="txtZipCode" />
    </form>
</body>
```

If I remove

```
<input type="text" id="txtZipCode" />
```

it will work properly. I think jquery tries to do something with the `textbox`.

what is the best way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The jQuery UI [`checkboxradio`](https://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/) plugin works on checkboxes with a label only, not on text inputs, and `$('input')` targets both tags, make sure you target the checkbox only, and jQuery UI will no longer throw the error when it tries to convert a text input into a radiobutton

```
$(function () {
    $("#cbxForRent").checkboxradio();
});
```

You could also target all checkboxes on the page with

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]')
```

or give them a common class to target them etc.

Comment: So I have to do that for all checkboxes? can I add a class for my checkboxes and apply on only that class?

Comment: @FLICKER - you can target them anyway you want, like `$('input[type="checkbox"]')` or give the elements you want to convert a common class. I just used an ID, as that's what you had, the important thing is to not target all inputs, as that includes inputs that aren't checkboxes

Comment: the solution you provided in answer, works but the one in comment which looks like a better solution, is not working. I tried $(input[type = "checkbox"]).checkboxradio();

Comment: Should work fine, but it looks like I forgot the quotes, I've added them now

Comment: Or the old standby [`$('input:checkbox')`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)....